# How do I make a grouping that includes only values from the list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table presented below.

```
+------+-------+--------------+------------------------------+------+
| good | store | date_id      | map_dates                    | sale |
+------+-------+--------------+------------------------------+------+
| 1    | 2     | '2019-01-01' | ['2018-07-08']               | 10   |
+------+-------+--------------+------------------------------+------+
| 1    | 2     | '2019-05-06' | ['2019-01-01', '2018-07-08'] | 5    |
+------+-------+--------------+------------------------------+------+
| 5    | 4     | '2019-10-12' | ['2018-12-01']               | 24   |
+------+-------+--------------+------------------------------+------+
| 1    | 2     | '2018-07-08' | []                           | 3    |
+------+-------+--------------+------------------------------+------+
| 5    | 4     | '2018-12-01' | []                           | 15   |
+------+-------+--------------+------------------------------+------+
```

I want to group by columns **good, store**, and include only the dates specified in the **map_dates** column in the result. For example:

```
+------+-------+--------------+----------+
| good | store | date_id      | sum_sale |
+------+-------+--------------+----------+
| 1    | 2     | '2019-01-01' | 3        |
+------+-------+--------------+----------+
| 1    | 2     | '2019-05-06' | 13       |
+------+-------+--------------+----------+
| 5    | 4     | '2019-10-12' | 15       |
+------+-------+--------------+----------+
```

How can I do this **without using a loop**?

Comment: How do you get your sum_sale? What's map_dates?

Comment: do your dates actually have a `'` around them?

Comment: For example, for good == 1, store == 2, date_id == '2019-05-06', I sum up sale, where good == 1, store == 2, and date_id in ['2019-01-01', '2018-07-08'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we explode, then we match our values by an `inner merge` on `good, store, map_dates` and `date_id`. Finally we `GroupBy.sum`:

```
dfn = df.explode('map_dates')
dfn = dfn.merge(dfn, 
                left_on=['good', 'store', 'map_dates'], 
                right_on=['good', 'store', 'date_id'],
                suffixes=['', '_sum'])

dfn = dfn.groupby(['good', 'store', 'date_id'])['sale_sum'].sum().reset_index(

   good  store     date_id  sale_sum
0     1      2  2019-01-01         3
1     1      2  2019-05-06        13
2     5      4  2019-10-12        15
```